# Activity does not scroll when rotating screen

Tags: android

when I turn the phone and the screen is rotating I cannot see the whole screen anymore. This is ok but I cannot scroll! Do I have to set some flag or property for scrolling? This is part of my xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="*">
        ...
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        ...
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put your complete layout inside a `ScrollView` in order for it to scroll.

It scrolls if your layout height is more than the screen height, which happens generally in landscape mode.

In your case put the `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`, since `ScrollView` can only have 1 child.

Comment: Tried that but now the activity crashes: process myapp stopped unexpectedly. Any ideas?

Comment: post your crash log may be, i cannot think of any reason why it should crash.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie, can you tell me how to get the log?

Comment: hmm, you generally get this in your logCat window, see what message you have in there.

Comment: Scrollview was not happy without any parameters: `<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >` Now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must know that in order to use an `scrollView` , **you must put only one component inside** (maybe a `linearLayout`) .Maybe that's your problem if you are trying to put in more components at that level.